# TypeError: to_sql() missing 1 required positional argument: 'con'

Tags: python, pandas

I have seen this question come up, but I thought I added a con into my code with sqlite3. What am I missing?

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('test_database')
c = conn.cursor()

df = pd.DataFrame.to_sql('reddit_api', conn)

for post in res.json()['data']['children']:
    df = df.append({
        'subreddit': post['data']['subreddit'],
        'title': post['data']['title'],
        'selftext':post['data']['selftext'],
        'upvote_ratio': post['data']['upvote_ratio'],
        'ups':post['data']['ups'],
        'downs':post['data']['downs'],
        'score':post['data']['score']
    }, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: What exactly you think you do with `df = pd.DataFrame.to_sql('reddit_api', conn)`? I think you want to use [pandas.read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html). Or move that line at the end, after you create `df` and use `df.to_sql('reddit_api', conn)`

Comment: There are also other problems - e.g. `res` is not defined.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.